# Reheating homemade meal

Tags: culinary-uses, reheating, frozen

About 1 week ago I made 2 of the same meal and froze one of them to eat at a later date. Both were cooked in the oven. I was wondering if it is possible to reheat the second meal straight from the freezer or do i need to let it thaw out. The meal is a ham casserole that has already been fully cooked.

Comment: You need to provide more details about how you froze it (packaging, size, and so on), how the casserole was composed (recipe would do), and so on.  It is certainly *safe* to begin rewarming the frozen product; the question is whether it is going to give you decent results.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in this situation, I would have frozen the 2nd meal in a zip lock bag.  Flatten the bag so that it is as thin as possible.  When ready to eat, thaw.  Bring a pot of water to a simmer.  Turn off heat.  Toss bag in water.  Let it reheat that way for 10 to 15 minutes.  Enjoy.  You can also do this directly from frozen. It will just take longer and would probably be better controlled in a low temp water bath.  But a pot of water can work too.